# Displaying Full DateTime when sorting by hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using microsoft sql server. I am trying to sort my results by the full time.

My raw data looks like this:

```
TimeStamp                           TotalOffered
2012-04-16 08:00:00                 18
2012-04-16 08:30:00                 34
2012-04-16 09:00:00                 30
2012-04-16 09:30:00                 68
```

I am sorting by hour blocks for example sum of data during 08:00:00 is 52, sum of data for 09:00:00 is 98, I have it broken down by day.

The Code i have is:

```
select datepart(hour,[TimeStamp]), SUM([TotalOffered])
from [my table]
group by 
datepart(hour,[sus_CallPerformance_TimeStamp]), 
dateadd(d, 0, datediff(d, 0, [sus_CallPerformance_TimeStamp]))
```

I am trying to get the data to show the full TimeStamp instead of just the hour.

Currently the results show as:

```
8   52
9   98
```

I would like the results to show as:

```
2012-04-16 08:00:00   52
2012-04-16 09:00:00   98
```

Thank You

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking, can you show your expected results?

Comment: Are you looking to sort by hour or group by hour?  Right now you are only grouping by hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStamp), DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, TimeStamp)) [TimeStamp],
        SUM(TotalOffered) [TotalOffered]
FROM    [My Table]
GROUP BY DATEADD(HOUR, DATEPART(HOUR, TimeStamp), DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, TimeStamp))
ORDER BY [TimeStamp]
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
declare @t table (ts datetime, od int)
insert into @t (ts, od) values ('2012-04-16 08:00:00', 18)
insert into @t (ts, od) values ('2012-04-16 08:30:00', 34)
insert into @t (ts, od) values ('2012-04-16 09:00:00', 30)
insert into @t (ts, od) values ('2012-04-16 09:30:00', 68)

select * from @t


select 
    dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, ts), cast(floor(cast(ts as real)) as datetime)) as solution,
    sum(od)
    from @t
    group by dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, ts), cast(floor(cast(ts as real)) as datetime))
    order by dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, ts), cast(floor(cast(ts as real)) as datetime))
```

Comment: Where is your `ORDER BY` clause? How do you expect your sort to be predictable without `ORDER BY`?

Comment: You only need that if you want to have the final results in order (like 8, 9, 10 o'clock, etc.) If that's not important, so you're fine with something like 7, 10, 9, 8, then it's absolutely OK, group by does the trick.

Comment: I thought that "sorting by hour" in the title made it pretty clear that ordering by 7, 10, 9, 8 would not make much sense.

Comment: 1. There was no order by clause in your original script so you yourself did not try to sort your original result set. 2. The key point in your question was obviously about displaying a datetime values rather than just the number. Anyway, double the last line and change "group by" to "order by".

Answer (score -1):

DateTime fields can be cast to floating point values, where the whole number represents the date and the fraction represents the time. If you multipy the date by 24, then the whole number will represent the hour, as follows:

```
SELECT CAST(FLOOR(CAST(TimeStamp AS FLOAT) * 24)/24.0 AS DateTime) AS Hr, SUM(TotalOffered) AS Total
FROM [my table]
GROUP BY FLOOR(CAST(TimeStamp AS FLOAT) * 24)
ORDER BY FLOOR(CAST(TimeStamp AS FLOAT) * 24)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this helps with sorting when there is no `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: DateTime fields are **NOT** stored in SQL Server internally as floating point values. [They are stored as two 4 byte integers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: I have added the order by clause, and removed the implication that DateTime fields are stored as float. Given that this code works, and works efficiently, perhaps the down-vote was a bit harsh?